# NPM Jquery Client vs Server Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I am fairly new to node and npm so this is a theoretical question.

I want so start using Jquery on my websites, so I did  `npm install jquery` and this created a node_modules directory inside my webpage directory along with my html, js and css files.

In order to make it work I had to add the following in my head tag in html `<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`

**Question 1)** Why npm installed node_modules directly into my directory? I would assume it would install it in my global directory `usr/local/lib/node_modules`

**Question 2)** If I would host the website somewhere else this would not work correct? I assume this method only works on client side.

**Question 3)** How would I have to setup my html or js in order to import jquery?

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to understand the mechanics of what I program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why npm installed node_modules directly into my directory? I would assume it would install it in my global directory usr/local/lib/node_modules

`npm` is designed to manage dependencies for a *project*. While you can make it install modules globally, this is really only intended for whole applications that are distributed via NPM.

> If I would host the website somewhere else this would not work correct? I assume this method only works on client side.

The `src` attribute needs to be a URL that resolves to the script file. If you don't upload the script to the right place then it won't resolve.

> How would I have to setup my html or js in order to import jquery?

With a `<script>` element.

---

Note that `npm` is *not* very good at managing dependencies for a client-side JavaScript project by itself. It only becomes useful when combined with a module system and a bundler such as browserify.

Comment: So something like this script ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>``` - this works, but raises the question in my head - why using npm at all?

Comment: You *could* use a CDN. You *shouldn't* use an obsolete and unsupported version of jQuery. NPM is great for managing complex module dependencies. You probably don't have those if you are using jQuery.